# Urn Problem - Martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

We have an urn that has 5 yellow balls and 3 black balls. After we choose a ball we replace it with 1 yellow and 1 black together. Let $Y_m$ be the amount of yellow balls after m draws.

Is $$X_m = \frac{Y_m}{2m+8}$$ a martingale?

So I know that at the end we will have $2m + 8$ balls. Then, $Y_m = n + 5$, which means that $$P(Y_{m+1}|Y_m=k) = \frac{n+5}{2n + 8}(k+1) + k \left(1-\frac{ n+5}{2n+8} \right)$$.

And that's where I stop and need guidance.

Comment: Correct we replace 1 black and 1 yellow together.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "After we choose a ball we replace it along with $1$ of each balls." Can you explain more clearly what happens after choosing a yellow ball, and after choosing a black ball?

Comment: That we replace a black and a yellow together regardless the ball we pick.

Answer (score 1):

Define the event $E_m$ as
$$E_m =\{\text{ the $m$th ball is yellow }\}.$$

Then, you can compute the conditional expectation using
$$\mathbf E[X_{m+1}|X_m] = \mathbf E[X_{m+1},E_m|X_m] + \mathbf E[X_{m+1},\neg E_m|X_m].$$

Now note that
$$\mathbf E[X_{m+1},E_m|X_m]=\mathbf E[X_{m+1}|E_m,X_m]P(E_m|X_m),$$
with a similar equation for $\mathbf E[X_{m+1},\neg E_m|X_m],$
where $P(E_m|X_m) = X_m$ is the probability of drawing a yellow ball at the $m$th draw.